# Align first line in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have horizontally oriented `LinearLayout` with `ImageView` and `TextView` in it (image at left, text at right). I want to align the first line of `TextView` (even if it has multiple lines) to the center of `ImageView`. How can I achieve that?

My current code, which centers the whole `TextView` instead of only the first line:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_distance" />

        <TextView
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            style="@style/taskAddressText"
            android:id="@+id/task_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I dont know whether it can be implemented, but what about using 2 textviews?

Answer (score 1):

You can set first line of TextView into centre of ImageView via getting height of ImageView at run time and divide that height into 2 for getting centre of ImageView then set top margin or padding to TextView as below :

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon_distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample address "/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Initialise views and set TextView Top padding from ImageView height at run time

```
 iconDistance = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon_distance);
 taskAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.task_address);

 ViewTreeObserver vto = iconDistance.getViewTreeObserver();
 vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
     public boolean onPreDraw() {
        iconDistance.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        int finalHeight = iconDistance.getMeasuredHeight();
        taskAddress.setPadding(0,(convertPixelsToDp(finalHeight)/2),0,0);
        return true;
     }
 });
```

Convert pixel into dp

```
public int convertPixelsToDp(int px){
   DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
   return (int) (px / ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing and why it works? Because I've tested it with my layout and the icon got centered with a 2-line textview, which does not seem what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Instead use a constraintLayout, create an invisible TextView with no text to guarantee it is always one line.  Then align the invisible text view to top and start of actual textview.

Then constrain the imageview to the invisible textview.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_distance" />

        <TextView
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            style="@style/taskAddressText"
            android:id="@+id/task_address"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have two `android:gravity="center_vertical"` in the text view... Was that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Top margin of the Text view = Half of the size of image view then it will always start from the center of the Image view.

```
Text View Top Margin = Image view Height /2
```

Comment: Do you save the height of the ImageView in a dimension and reference it, or how do you achieve this?